ReactJS Install
i've been trying to install reactjs to visual studio code after alot of troubleshooting i can't seem to get it to install probably just wondering if anyone has had this issue and knows how to fix it
PS C:\Users\PCname\Desktop\ReactJS> npx create-react-app react-learning
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\PCname\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\PCname\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PCname\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-08-28T10_03_40_865Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\PCname\Desktop\ReactJS>
i've tried uninstalling and re-installing everything that connects to this icluding deleting any files that wasn't unistalled i confirm that everything was done correctly, i've checked all updates and to confirm i did it correctly i followed step by step guides i could find but still no cigar

Make sure to be inside a folder you have write access to.
Also are you sure that you are running the command:
npx create-react-app react-learning
EDIT:
Thank you for pointing out that CRA is deprecated. Instead you could try running
npx create-next-app@latest
(taken from React's installation tutorial)
And if that doesn't work out. Share with us the error logs that are being saved inside C:\Users\PCname\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-08-28T10_03_40_865Z-debug-0.log

CRA is deprecated as it was abandoned.

create-react-app is deprecated and the React docs advised against initialising a new project with it.
